# How do I import a .dmp file into Oracle?

Tags: oracle, import

I have a `.dmp` file that I would like to import into Oracle 9i. How do I do that?

Answer (score 29):

Presuming you have a .dmp file created by oracle exp then

```
imp help=y
```

will be your friend. It will lead you to

```
imp file=<file>.dmp show=y
```

to see the contents of the dump and then something like

```
imp scott/tiger@example file=<file>.dmp fromuser=<source> touser=<dest>
```

to import from one user to another. Be prepared for a long haul though if it is a complicated schema as you will need to precreate all referenced schema users, and tablespaces to make the imp work correctly

Comment: all the table are transform but not the data of the table please help

Comment: I'd like to emphasize what kblair wrote in his last paragraph. In our case (~3000 tables with hundreds of schemas/users) we spent quite some time looking at all the errors in the log file created by imp - and used those to manually create all the necessary CREATE TABLESPACE commands, and then all the CREATE USER commands for the users that (for various reasons) were not created by imp. Once the tablespaces and users were in place, the import worked.

Answer (score 10):

I am Using Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2.

Follow the Steps:

**Open run SQl Command Line**

Step 1: Login as system user

```
       SQL> connect system/tiger
```

Step 2 : `SQL> CREATE USER  UserName IDENTIFIED BY Password;`

Step 3 : `SQL> grant dba to UserName ;`

Step 4 : `SQL> GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO UserName;`

Step 5:

```
        SQL> CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE TSD_UserName
             DATAFILE 'tbs_perm_03.dat'
             SIZE 8G
             AUTOEXTEND ON;
```

**Open Command Prompt in Windows or Terminal in Ubuntu. Then Type:**

**Note : if you Use Ubuntu then replace " \" to " /" in path.**

Step 6: `C:\> imp UserName/password@localhost file=D:\abc\xyz.dmp log=D:\abc\abc_1.log full=y;`

Done....

I hope you Find Right solution here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
imp system/system-password@SID file=directory-you-selected\FILE.dmp log=log-dir\oracle_load.log fromuser=infodba touser=infodba commit=Y
```

Comment: Deepak this is code dump with no commentary to help anyone.

Answer (score 2):

i got solution what you are getting as per `imp help=y` it is mentioned that imp is only valid for `TRANSPORT_TABLESPACE` as below:

```
Keyword  Description (Default)       Keyword      Description (Default)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
USERID   username/password           FULL         import entire file (N)
BUFFER   size of data buffer         FROMUSER     list of owner usernames
FILE     input files (EXPDAT.DMP)    TOUSER       list of usernames
SHOW     just list file contents (N) TABLES       list of table names
IGNORE   ignore create errors (N)    RECORDLENGTH length of IO record
GRANTS   import grants (Y)           INCTYPE      incremental import type
INDEXES  import indexes (Y)          COMMIT       commit array insert (N)
ROWS     import data rows (Y)        PARFILE      parameter filename
LOG      log file of screen output   CONSTRAINTS  import constraints (Y)
DESTROY                overwrite tablespace data file (N)
INDEXFILE              write table/index info to specified file
SKIP_UNUSABLE_INDEXES  skip maintenance of unusable indexes (N)
FEEDBACK               display progress every x rows(0)
TOID_NOVALIDATE        skip validation of specified type ids
FILESIZE               maximum size of each dump file
STATISTICS             import precomputed statistics (always)
RESUMABLE              suspend when a space related error is encountered(N)
RESUMABLE_NAME         text string used to identify resumable statement
RESUMABLE_TIMEOUT      wait time for RESUMABLE
COMPILE                compile procedures, packages, and functions (Y)
STREAMS_CONFIGURATION  import streams general metadata (Y)
STREAMS_INSTANTIATION  import streams instantiation metadata (N)
DATA_ONLY              import only data (N)

The following keywords only apply to transportable tablespaces
TRANSPORT_TABLESPACE import transportable tablespace metadata (N)
TABLESPACES tablespaces to be transported into database
DATAFILES datafiles to be transported into database
TTS_OWNERS users that own data in the transportable tablespace set
```

So, Please create table space for your user:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE <tablespace name> DATAFILE <path to save, example: 'C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\ABC.dbf'> SIZE 100M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 100M MAXSIZE 10G EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL UNIFORM SIZE 1M;
```

Answer (score -1):

.dmp files are dumps of oracle databases created with the "exp" command. You can import them using the "imp" command.

If you have an oracle client intalled on your machine, you can executed the command

imp help=y

to find out how it works. What will definitely help is knowing from wich schema the data was exported and what the oracle version was.

Comment: that really doesn't answer anything

Comment: That's how it goes when trying to find solutions to problems with Oracle. It seems like knowing how Oracle works is the most precious commodity in the world. Sharing this knowledge is like casting your pearls before swine.